Going to lunatic asylums - Date of Order v Date of Admission
I am doing some research on a family member from 1893 when she went to a lunatic asylum.
I have visited the Dorset History Centre and obtained photos of the relevant documentation:

Pauper Order Paper. NG-HH/CMR/4/32G; Ref: 3859;
Admission Register. NG-HH/CMR/4/1/1; Page: 12;

I have other references, but the above will do. In summary:

Date of Order: Feb 1st, 1893
Date of Admission: Feb 7th, 1893
Date of Admission: July 7th, 1893

At the moment I have collated both sources under a single fact:

It is not clear to me when Mary actually went to the asylum. On the 1st Feb? And should I have 2 distinct facts?
As for the dates:

The order paper mentions the 1st Feb and 7th July.
The register paper mentions 7th Feb.
The patient records mention 7th Feb.


Update
I wonder, the Order paper must be saying 7 Feby 1893:

Looks like July but makes sense to be Feby!

Could you clarify the format and arrangements of the records in question? E.g. the Admissions book with the month of February spelled out in full appears to be in a bound book. Unless a book had fallen apart and been mis-bound, one might expect the records to be in order chronologically. What format do the order records come in and how are they arranged?

P.S. when copying entries from a register book (one line per patient/research subject) one can sometimes figure out dates from seeing the context of the full page, but even then one has to take care in case the register is a copy book and/or entries have been made out of order.  The same applies to books where the records are in 1 page per person format, if an error was made or there are special circumstances, then records can be in a bound book wildly out of place from their chronology. But browsing the book if possible can give you other pages to compare, show context, etc.

@JanMurphy All books apart from the order papers which were loose. And yes, the patient records skip back and forth. But in this case I think I simply misread Feby as July.

I can happily read that admission date in the last image as "Feby" - it's that darn "J" that looks like so many other letters. Or, the reverse in this case.

The date issues aside, a lot of people were in and out of asylums, prisons, or other institutions, so it may or may not be useful/practical to record these as "Residence" facts. You might end up needing a dozen facts if she was not in the asylum all thee timee. I would also argue that often with these types of admissions, it might be misleading to call this a Residence. Of course, some people lived in the same institution for years, but many did not.
If wishing to record these as facts (which you might not need to — I often simply put these details in notes), I would suggest it may be more accurate to create a custom fact for the particular type of admission. You could call the fact type Asylum Admission or Hospital Admission or Imprisonment or Orphanage Admission, as the case may be.
Now, to the date issue, it depends on which fact type you use. If you are going to use Residence, then it would be false to record the date as the order date. The Residence date would be from when she started living there, which is presumably the admission date. Unless she lived there until her death, there is likely some record somewhere of when she was discharged.
If not sure which is the correct admission date, it is best not to guess (as that could mislead others). In that case, simply enter the year - 1893, or abt 1893. If you know when she was discharged, then a year range may be simplest, e.g. 1893-1895.

Thanks for the thoughts. In Mary's case, he remained at the asylum until her death on 1st May, 1919 and there are several associated census records confirming this. But I get what you are saying re. using a custom fact.

See my updated question. Think I solved the mystery.

To me, the important question is whether the admission was 7 February or 7 July. Without a detailed reading of the text and a detailed knowledge of the medical procedures, a definitive answer is surely impossible. But it would appear to me that the primary purpose of the Order paper is to document the order made on 1 February, and it would surely have been updated with the date of admission after that. It is, therefore, a secondary source for the date of admission, whereas the register and patient records are surely contemporary with the admission.
Usual story, then, the secondary source of some information is more likely to suffer any errors due to mistranscription. Doesn't mean it's definitely wrong, just probably - especially given 2 references in the (presumed) contemporary papers to 7 February.
So I'd go for admission on 7 February but please ensure you make a note about the discrepancy somewhere obvious. Maybe the update to the Order paper was made in July so that month was in the clerk's head.
As for one or two facts? Generally it's a matter of preference - if you have a lot of admissions it might make sense to treat them in a more detailed manner and split them, but I suspect that simple is best: Residence from 7 February, and a note against that residence saying "Order made 1 February".

Alright, your reasoning makes sense! I have limited it to a single fact, with the following text: "Mary Coke was admitted to the Dorset County Asylum on the 7th of February, 1893, following an order issued on the 1st of February of the same year.". Then, in her general notes, I have added: "there is a notable discrepancy in the documentation, as the admission date recorded on the order paperwork is incorrectly listed as the 1st of July, 1893. This inconsistency raises questions about the accuracy of the administrative records surrounding her case."

I still need to transcribe her patient notes and have another set of records to review for her sister Maria who was also at the same asylum.

See my updated question. Think I solved the mystery.
